# How to automatically feed two arguments to program after startup?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, mysql, vagrant

I have this following script which works fine on ubuntu for starting and creating a new table for MySQL database:

```
echo "CREATE DATABASE database_name" | mysql -u root -p
```

After this command is executed MySQL asks for password.

The only problem is that I want to do this on vagrant provision bash script, so I have to automate the process of entering the password. I basically have to give a single line of input to the MySQL program like this:

```
Enter password: password_goes_here
```

How do I combine the process of entering the database creation command and the password as text to the program?

Comment: Title mentions "two arguments". Password is one, the other?

Comment: The other is the sql statement `CREATE DATABASE database_name`

Comment: But it is not provided "after startup". Anyway what's the problem here? Why can't you provide password as an argument?

Comment: The server asks for password after the `mysql -u root -p` command. As this command is executed from vagrant provision script there is no way to provide the password manually. I don't know though if the password could be provided int the `mysql` command arguments though.

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no way to provide the password manually"?

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the options for mysql command thoroughtly rnought it seems that I can provide the password int he command like so: `mysql -u root --password=mypassword_here`

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution for this specific question is to provide the password in the `mysql` commands parameters as follows:

```
echo "CREATE DATABASE database_name" | mysql -u root --password=your_password
```

This provides the mysql with the password before it even gets to ask for it.

Answer (score 2):

[@The-amateur-programmer's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265657/78871) is great, but I just wanted to add one thing to it. If you're worried about your password being visible when someone runs `ps auxwww`, you can also feed the password to MySQL using an Environment Variable called `MYSQL_PWD`:

```
mysql> set password for 'will@localhost' = PASSWORD('test');
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

$ export MYSQL_PWD=test
$ mysql -uwill@localhost
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.
```

This, and other options, are explained [here in the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/password-security-user.html).

Comment: Thanks for this information. Though in this situation this is not a problem as the server is only accessed through localhost and is not visible externally so it's okay for the password to be visible.